# Why is TypeScript giving this error: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Column<T, K>'. (2339)

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function `printSize` that should print the `size` of a `Column` if that `Column` has a `size`. In the function definition below, why is the error given when I try to access the `size` property? What can I change to make this work?

You can see the error on this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-frog-xvm8d).

```
export type BaseColumn = {
    name: string
}

export type VarcharColumn = {
    type: 'varchar'
    size: number
}

export interface IntColumn {
    type: 'int'
}

export type TypedColumn<T, K extends keyof T> = 
    T[K] extends string ? VarcharColumn 
    : IntColumn

type Column<T, K extends keyof T> = BaseColumn & TypedColumn<T, K>

interface Post {
    id: number
    title: string
}

const printSize = <T, K extends keyof T>(col: Column<T, K>) => {
    if (col.type === 'varchar') {
        console.log(col.size)
        //              ^^^^ Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Column<T, K>'. (2339)
    }
}

printSize<Post, 'title'>({ name: 'title', type: 'varchar', size: 100 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript compiler supports type guards that narrow **union types** based on discriminant property, but `Column<T, K>` is not a union type.

To make this work, you could use [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) with same "user facing" signature, but in the implementation use a union type instead:

```
function printSize<T, K extends keyof T>(col: Column<T, K>): void
function printSize(col: IntColumn | VarcharColumn) {
    if (col.type === 'varchar') {
        console.log(col.size)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBDAzsAwhAGwFcBbAOzgF44BvAKDkbjIxOAC44sYoBLMgOZ0AvnTqhIsBMlQA1DFADGACwX5i5KrQZMkKTgHIAbgpUKDOxll4AvDs1IAjYFBFiJ0ePxguAZhkVUAEkyGHVSCnomaX04A28LUXFwTxjUABUZABNw8gAedIAaOABpOFAfMiysOABrYEQIXzh0gD4tSxaAbRKAXXKQSuquHn4BOAB%20OHklVShcik7OELDCCLE9VAWC4rKK4Cqa%20sbmtq1MHAW4ADIW7O2i0taxbz8A1AAFCG5taN4szhkJwuTowXgwAj2bh8QRuOi%20IhkRRgiAUMAwmAAZVswB2pQGQyODSaLVaAApFIROA9dq0AJScIwQf7wxHI3iouDo7zYuwUqlwFZXAA%2001McwWdN%20TF4zX5BAAdJsqJRqMZxeYpVFokxKWQsIRgAqCBABPKFdY7HTOqIktzQrzcV9uMUDGCIcADOSaMxWPY3eDIQZiptDCZZuZipb7ABGAAMcbgwjpQA)